# How to restart keyboard input method without logout/in in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-input

I am using nabi (keyboard input method) to switch between Hangul(Korean) and English. A few days ago, I changed my keyboard with no Hangul key, which was the toggle key. I changed the toggle key setting in nabi to shift + space, but it seems to have no effect until I logout and login again (so that nabi restarts). But currently, this machine is transferring data that will not end in a few weeks. While I don't want to stop the data transfer, I want to restart the input method or change toggle key. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

How to restart keyboard layout without logout/in in linux

> I am using Ubuntu 20.04, for me it worked to change the keyboard language from US English to Latin American Spanish without logout/in :

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

      Keyboard Model: Generic 105-key PC
      Country Keyboard: Spanish (Latin America)
      Keyboard Layout: Spanish (Latin America)
      The default for the keyboard layout
      No compose key
```

```
$ sudo setupcon
```

This could also help https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard

[image: asciicast]

Comment: perfect! The only solution i found so far that made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check your keyboard driver. A faulty driver could be causing issues with your keyboard.

- Click the .Hardware tab.
- Select your keyboard from the list of devices.
- Click .Properties.
- Click the .Driver tab.
- Click the .Roll Back Driver button.

Comment: sorry, but this is for linux not windows